# How do I use the Instagram's API in Python to grab media/user information?

Tags: python, api, httprequest, instagram, media

I've tried several things from the documentation and it hasn't worked. This code is from the documentation of https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/master/README.md

```
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

Here is the error:

> in _do_api_request
>       raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'],
>   content_obj['meta']['error_message'])
>   instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) OAuthAccessTokenException-The
>   access_token provided is invalid.

Comment: ***"The access_token provided is invalid"*** - This means you need a valid token... You may use http://instagram.pixelunion.net/ to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `README` file on that GitHub repo. [Here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/master/README.md#obtaining-an-access-token) it explains what you need to do to obtain an Access Token.

Comment: I still get an error when following the simple documentation